# Data warehouse type 2 scd Employee dimension and HR Facts (Kimball's)

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I'm following the "Data Warehouse Toolkit" book by Kimball and I'm getting confused with an example of an employee dimension and a HR snapshot fact table.

Here is a screenshot of the example given in the book:

[image: sreenshot]

I'm getting confused with the 'Employee count', 'New Hire Count', 'Transfer Count' and 'Promotion Count' fields. As you can see there is a relationship between the HR fact table and the Employee dimension table but which key would be assigned in the fact table in the case of these count values?. I understand that there could be a 'New Hire Count' at the end of the month and we would have Month Dimension FK in the fact table pointing to that month, but what about the employee dimension key?

I hope I'm making myself clear here, and sorry if somehow this is a dumb question.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I can't see a relationship between the HR fact table and the Employee dimension table.  Are you referring to the Employee Transaction Dimension and Human Resources Snapshot Fact tables?

Comment: @DanBracuk Yes sorry, by Employee dimension I meant the "Employee Transaction Dimension".

Answer (score 1):

stigma,
I believe the surrogate key of the most recent row from `Employee Transaction Dimension` is what one would include in the fact table.  There may be multiple rows in `Employee Transaction Dimension` for the month, but only the most recent one would be referenced in the fact table row for a given month.

Hope this helps.

Best Regards,
Jesse Dyson

Answer (score 1):

In a SCD (type 2 or type 3), you want to think in terms of 2 types of key; natural keys and pseudo keys.  The natural key is the identifier which the "real world" would understand, in the example of an Employee dimension, this would probably be some kind of Employee Id.  Each time you add an entry to this table, you get a new pseudo key, and I like to think of this as the "as-was" key.  It represents the state of that dimensional member "as it was", when the record was added.

Over time in a SCD, you will have many, many records per natural key, each with it's own "as-was" key.  Considering the most recent entry, it's "as-was" key is also the "as-is" key, as it represents the current state.

In a fact table, you should ALWAYS expect to find the "as-was" key.  If you're going to assume the fact table will always hold the "as-is" key, or the most recent key, then it assumes you're going to go back and update historical records in your fact table simply because an attribute of the dimension changed.  This is a waste of resources for started, and is actually counter-productive as one of the major benefits of a SCD is the ability to do "as-was vs as-is" analysis, and to do this you need to preserve the "as-was" state.